# PHP Repeating Print Statement

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with a PHP print statement that repeats the output continuously for about 40 or 50 times, then stops.  I thought it was supposed to print only one line.  I'm still somewhat new to PHP, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  The code in question is located at the bottom of the snippet.

Thanks in advance.....

```
 <?php
$query = $_POST['query'];
find_files('.');

function find_files($seed) {
    if(! is_dir($seed)) return false;

    $files = array();
    $dirs = array($seed);

    while(NULL !== ($dir = array_pop($dirs))) {
        if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while( false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {
                if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
                $path = $dir . '/' . $file;
                if(is_dir($path)) { 
                    $dirs[] = $path; 
                } else { 
                    if(preg_match('/^.*\.(php[\d]?|js|txt)$/i', $path)) { 
                        check_files($path); 
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}

function check_files($this_file) {
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $str_to_find = $query;

    if ((isset($str_to_find)) && (empty($str_to_find))) {
        print '<p>Your search produced no results</p>';
    } else {
        if(!($content = file_get_contents($this_file))) { 
            echo("<p>Could not check $this_file</p>\n"); 
        } else { 
            if(stristr($content, $str_to_find)) { 
                echo("<p>$this_file -> contains $str_to_find</p>\n"); 
            }
        }
        unset($content);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it 'Your search produced no results' that's repeating?

Comment: Perhaps you are calling Checkfiles repeatedly (hinted at by spencercw)? ->check_files($path); It's in a while() loop, so it will print every time that sections loops.

Comment: user978122, thanks for the info.  that makes sense.....is there a way to prevent the echo statement from par-taking in this "while" statement?

Comment: @RobMyrick Your code is in dire need of proper formatting.

Comment: @user978122 Just move it outside of the function. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Your search produced no results' will be printed out once for every file that your loop sees.  You should do the check before you call `find_files()`:

```
if (!isset($str_to_find) || empty($str_to_find)) {
    print '<p>Your search produced no results</p>';
} else {
    find_files('.');
}
```

You can then remove that bit of code from `check_files()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the print statement inside of the `check_files()` function, which is being called from inside your `while...` loop.  So, yes, it's going to be executed each time that loop executes and the conditions match.

Answer (score 0):

By `!==` you maybe meant `!=`?

Comment: `===` just means 'exactly equals' and doesn't do things like converting strings to ints. It's generally a good idea to always use `===` and `!==`.